# re-inserting failed records from a set of records

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

```
ID     ERROR    STOCK        TRD_DATE          AUDIT_DATETIME
101692579 Y     US9128      15-AUG-18 00.00.00  15-AUG-18 17.01.07 --gets missed
101692555 Y     US9128      15-AUG-18 00.00.00  15-AUG-18 17.21.07
101692555 Y     US9128      15-AUG-18 00.00.00  15-AUG-18 17.11.07
101692555 Y     US9128      15-AUG-18 00.00.00  15-AUG-18 17.07.35
101692572 Y     US912828    15-AUG-18 00.00.00  15-AUG-18 17.21.07
101692572 Y     US912828    15-AUG-18 00.00.00  15-AUG-18 17.11.07
101692572 Y     US912828    15-AUG-18 00.00.00  15-AUG-18 17.07.35
101692573 Y     US912       15-AUG-18 00.00.00  15-AUG-18 17.21.07
101692573 Y     US912       15-AUG-18 00.00.00  15-AUG-18 17.11.07
```

Table: Trade

I have scheduled job that runs at the following times:

```
17:00
17:10
17:20
17:30
```

The job queries the above `Trade` table for records that are in ERROR state, for example `where ERROR = Y` and then will re-insert these bad trades back into the same table hence why there are repeats in above table example at different schedules. The query used to pick up these trades looks like this at the moment:

```
select
a.id,
a.error,
a.stock,
a.trd_date,
a.audit_datetime
from trade a
where to_char(audit_datetime, 'yyyymmdd') = to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmdd')
and error = 'Y'
and to_char(a.audit_datetime, 'yyyymmddhh24mi') >= (select max(to_char(audit_datetime, 'yyyymmddhh24mi'))-1 from trade) --check for previous run errors
```

I am relying on `max(audit_datetime)` atm:

I have two issues which I have not been able to correct:

1. When job runs @ 17:10 for example, I expect the below records to be picked up
   for re-insert into Trade table, but the first one is missed:

   ```
   101692579 Y     US9128      15-AUG-18 00.00.00  15-AUG-18 17.01.07 --gets missed
   101692555 Y     US9128      15-AUG-18 00.00.00  15-AUG-18 17.07.35
   101692572 Y     US912828    15-AUG-18 00.00.00  15-AUG-18 17.07.35
   ```

I understand this is because of the last filter in my sql where the ***audit_datetime < max(audit_datetime)-1***. What alternative can i do to fix this? I do not want to hardcode any given time from where it should look query from. How can I change query to take into account minimum(first record in my set)?

2. I would like to prevent inserting duplicate re-inserts in one run with a correct improved sql, for example DO NOT want to pick up three and re-insert @ 17:30 schedule:

   ```
     101692572 Y     US912828    15-AUG-18 00.00.00  15-AUG-18 17.21.07
     101692572 Y     US912828    15-AUG-18 00.00.00  15-AUG-18 17.11.07
     101692572 Y     US912828    15-AUG-18 00.00.00  15-AUG-18 17.07.35
   ```

The query should look at maximum of the three for a given id and re-insert only one. So these are the ones that should get re-inserted @ 17:30 :

```
101692555 Y     US9128      15-AUG-18 00.00.00  15-AUG-18 17.21.07
101692572 Y     US912828    15-AUG-18 00.00.00  15-AUG-18 17.21.07
101692573 Y     US912       15-AUG-18 00.00.00  15-AUG-18 17.21.07
```

Comment: Can you create a sql fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/)? Easier to analse the query.

Comment: Aren't you looking for 10 minutes before the current run's time? E.g. at 17:10, you should be looking for anything beyond 17:00, i.e. `sysdate - 10/1440`. Or, better, would be to have a table that stores the timestamp of the job runs (if there isn't already one, eg. if you're using dbms_scheduler jobs, there's dba_scheduler_job_run_details) and use that to work out when the last job started, and then you can use that to work out the times to look between.

Comment: @Boneist - thats correct. I need to check errors from previous run. I am not using dbms scheduler but business intelligence SSIS.

Comment: @M06H is there a table there that logs the start times of when the job ran? If not, `a.audit_datetime >= sysdate - 10/1440` is probably your best bet (but it may lead to duplications/missing info if the job starts early/late). If that's the case, I would change your job to log to a table first thing, so that you know the time period to look between.

Comment: @Boneist - thanks will explore the logging time to table option